# How do I get the JodaModule to do withZoneUTC() date format through Jackson?

Tags: jackson, jodatime, jackson-modules

So I've got my Jackson and Joda support all set up...

```
ext.jackson = [version: '2.3.2']
...
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:${jackson.version}"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${jackson.version}"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:${jackson.version}"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:${jackson.version}"
```

And my OjbectMapper configured to use the JodaModule() to format java.util.Dates

```
private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
static {
    // JodaModule gets Dates handled as ISO-8601 strings
    JodaModule jodaModule = new JodaModule();
    mapper.registerModule( jodaModule );
    mapper.configure( SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false );
}
```

But I can't figure out how to get the JodaModlue to format the java.util.Date occurrences in my POJOs like "2014-02-07T21:29:19.032Z" rather than "2014-02-07T21:29:19.032+0000".  When I do this "stand-alone" in Joda the incantation is ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZoneUTC().  How can I jack that DateTimeFormatter into the JodaModule() I push into the ObjectMapper?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, use of annotation `@JsonFormat(pattern="...")`, but I think this improvement (make Joda module datatypes recognize and use `@JsonFormat`) is only going to be included in 2.4.0. But once that happens it will be available (it already works for JDK date/time types, FWIW).

But you may want to file a feature request (issue at github tracker) for Joda module, to specifically request a simple feature for Joda module for "optimizing" output of UTZ timezone.

Comment: I might go the "issue tracker" path.  Thanks for the suggestion.  In the interim, what I discovered is that I do get the "2014-02-07T21:29:19.032Z" output if my POJO doesn't use java.util.Date but, rather, org.joda.time.DateTime.  I'm leaning towards this as the correct answer for my question; you can't get there from java.util.Date, but leverage org.joda.time.DateTime and you are golden.